# Compute once, use multiple times within Python class

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, numpy, scipy

I am trying to define a class within which a function of many variables is optimized. Normally I'm working with ~500-1000 variables. In this class, I need to pass function and its derivative to `minimize` in `scipy` to find the `x0` which minimizes this function.

The following is a simple working example of the concept and it works fine. But as you see both the function (`f`) and its derivative (`df`) depend on another function `g` (In this example, it looks trivial and can be written in another way but actual functions are much more complicated).

I was wondering if I can calculate `g` only once at each iteration and then use that value within the class. Considering that `f` and `df` get updated in `minimize` multiple times so at each step `g` should be re-evaluated as well.

Thanks!

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

class Minimization(object):
    '''A class to optimizae a function'''

    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.p = np.array([x,y])

    def g(self,x,y):
        return x-y

    def f(self,p):
        return (self.g(*p) - 1)**2

    def df(self,p):
        fprime = 2*(self.g(*p) - 1)
        return np.array([fprime,-fprime])

    def optimize(self):
        P1 = minimize(fun=self.f, x0=self.p, args=(), method='Newton-CG',jac=self.df)
        return P1

    m = Minimization(2,4)
    m.optimize()
     #fun: 0.0
    # jac: array([ 0., -0.])
 #message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
  #  nfev: 3
   # nhev: 0
    # nit: 2
    #njev: 6
  #status: 0
 #success: True
  #     x: array([ 3.5,  2.5])
```

Comment: What iterations?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Iterations are inside minimize.

Comment: The iterations are handled by scipy in the function `minimize`, which repeatedly evaluates `self.f` as it searches for the minimum.

Comment: I would have chose the answer of Paul for multiple reasons. But it is up to you. Caching is commonly performed as it stands in Paul's answer. BTW, note that testing if a value is `None` as done in cmclen's is not recommended, since this can lead to ambiguous comparisons. What if `self._value` is equal to 0 or a Nd array?? The common manner to test this is `if self._value is not None`.

Comment: @Kanak: Thank you for pointing this out! That was a mistake, I meant to choose Paul's answer that I ended up using!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is called "memoizing".  When the function g calculates a value it stores the result in a dictionary, indexed by the arguments x, y.  Every time g is called it checks the dictionary to see if the value it needs is already stored there.  If you need to reset the values, you clear the dictionary.  Something like this:

```
class Minimization(object):
    '''A class to optimizae a function'''

    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.p = np.array([x,y])
        self.cache = {}  # previously computed values of g

    def g(self,x,y):
        cache_index = (x, y)
        if cache_index in self.cache:  # check cache first
            return self.cache[cache_index]
        value = x - y
        self.cache[cache_index] = value  # save for later
        return value

    def f(self,p):
        return (self.g(*p) - 1)**2

    def df(self,p):
        fprime = 2*(self.g(*p) - 1)
        return np.array([fprime,-fprime])

    def optimize(self):
        self.cache.clear()  # Blow the cache
        P1 = minimize(fun=self.f, x0=self.p, args=(), method='Newton-CG',jac=self.df)
        return P1
```

Comment: `self.cache[cache_index] = value` raises an `unhashable type` **error** if `x` and/or `y` are `numpy.ndarray` objects.

Answer (score 1):

Without having looked too deeply at the code itself, here is a sample class to demonstrate how to calculate a value once and avoid recomputing it on each invocation. You could also make this a property.

```
class StackOverflow:
     def __init__(self, value=None):
             self._value = value
     def compute_value(self):
             if self._value is None:
                     self._value = 100  # Compute value here
             return self._value
```

Comment: What if `self._value` is equal to 0?

Comment: Good call @Kanak, should be checking if `self._value is None`. I made the change in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

*To complement Paul's answer*, you could define a class aggregating caching-like methods that you will then (re-) use as decorator.

```
import functools as ft #<------ used to keep meth-related docstring

class Cache(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._cache = {}

    @classmethod
    def _property(cls, meth):
        @property
        @ft.wraps(meth)
        def __property(cls):
            meth_name = meth.__name__
            if meth_name not in cls._cache:
                cls._cache[meth_name] = meth(cls)
            return cls._cache[meth_name]
        return __property

    @classmethod
    def _method(cls, meth):
        @ft.wraps(meth)
        def __method(cls, *args, **kwargs):
            meth_key = '{}_{}'.format(meth.__name__, args)# <---- considered as string so as avoid unhashable-type errors
            if meth_key not in cls._cache:
                cls._cache[meth_key] = meth(cls, *args, **kwargs)
            return cls._cache[meth_key]
        return __method
```

And then using the class `Cache` as ancestor to `Minimization`, as follows

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

class Minimization(Cache):#<----------Inherits of Cache instead of object
    '''A class to optimizae a function'''

    def __init__(self,x,y):
        super(Minimization,self).__init__()
        self.x0 = x               # I changed the names because as it stands, 
        self.y0 = y               # these attributes are actually used as first guesses
        self.p0 = np.array([x,y]) # for the resolution process

    @Cache._method
    def g(self, x, y):
        return x - y

    #@Cache._method
    def f(self,p):
        return (self.g(*p) - 1)**2

    #@Cache._method
    def df(self,p):
        fprime = 2*(self.g(*p) - 1)
        return np.array([fprime,-fprime])

    @Cache._property
    def optimized(self):#<----- I changed the name into optimized to make it representative of what it is, a property
        return minimize(fun=self.f, x0=self.p0, args=(), method='Newton-CG',jac=self.df)
```

**Use Case** *(tested under Python 2.7.11 and 3.6.1)*

```
>>> m = Minimization(2,4)
>>> # Take care to clear the cache if optimized is not called for the first time and that you changed one of its "dependencies", doing m._cache.clear().
>>> # something you may want to do is simply removing the @Cache._property decorator 
>>> m.optimized
  status: 0
 success: True
    njev: 6
    nfev: 3
     fun: 0.0
       x: array([ 3.5,  2.5])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nhev: 0
     jac: array([ 0., -0.])
```

Comment: Nice idea but I see some possible problems.  In `_method` you turn the argument list into a string, but that's not guaranteed to work: different Python objects aren't required to have different string representations; unhashable objects are unhashable for a reason (typically because they have internal state that's not tied to their hash value), and converting them to a string doesn't solve that problem.  Not to mention that a string conversion might be expensive.  And the string doesn't take into account keyword arguments, which could affect the returned value of the function.

Comment: The method `_property` doesn't work for the OP's original problem, since the second time you call `optimized` it will return the same value it got the first time.  That's not what OP wanted - he wanted to flush the cache at that point, which your approach will not allow.

Comment: @PaulCornelius. ***First***, note that your cache's tuple keys, i.e. `cache_index = (x, y)`, have even less chances to work than when they are turned into their string representation. ***Then*** when you say "different Python objects aren't required to have different string representations", note that the objects in question in the OP's case will either be floats or numpy.arrays. And those possess a string representation (py27/3.+). ***Finally*** you are right, clearing the cache inside `optimized` has no effect. It must actually simply be performed before calling the attribute. It's a *typo*.

Comment: @PaulCornelius. Regarding kwargs, you are right. Something that can be done is also to turn it into its string representation, i.e. `'{}_{}_{}'.format(meth.__name__, args, kwargs)`.

Comment: In my code I don't do any string conversion but use the tuple `cache_index` directly as the dictionary key.  I don't know what you mean when you say that this will have less chances to work, because it will work 100% of the time and doesn't involve the overhead of string conversion.  Also I'm not sure that converting `kwargs` to a string will always work: I don't think that 2 dictionaries that are actually equal will always have the same string representation (since the order of keys is not guaranteed).

Comment: @PaulCornelius.Try this `{(1,np.zeros((1,1))):None}` on the one hand and `{(1,str(np.zeros((1,1)))):None}` on the other hand. Do you see my point now ? Relatively to the not garanteed kwargs order of keys, you are right.